# I dont know what is wrong with my html and php code.It gives Error:Query was empty

Tags: php, html, mysql

`<body>`

```
<h1><center>PHARMA DEVELOPMENT</center></h1>
<form name="reg" action="insert.php"  method="post">
<table width="274" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="95"><div align="right">username:</div></td>
<td width="171"><input type="text" name="phpro_username" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">Password:</div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="phpro_password" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">city:</div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="city" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">state:</div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="state" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">Country.:</div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="country" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right"></div></td>
<td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>      
</body>


insert.php `<?php`
```

`$con = mysql_connect("localhost","uai","dev@123");`
`if (!$con)`
`{`

```
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("reference", $con);

$username =$_POST['phpro_username'];
$password =$_POST['phpro_password'];
$city =$_POST['city'];
$state =$_POST['state'];
$country =$_POST['country'];
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO phpro_salsrep(phpro_username, phpro_password, city, state, country) VALUES('$username','$password','$city','$state','$country')");
if (!mysql_query($result,$con))
{
echo "inserted sucessfully";
}
else
{
die('Error:' .mysql_error());
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Run in apache server... - like (WAMP,XAMP) the only php file will work.

Comment: first of you should not use the `mysql_*` extensions anymore as it is deleted in PHP 7.0 and it does not support prepared statements second don't mix extensions you should only use or mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: why are there two connections the same? And why mix mysql with mysqli?

Comment: Also add some more text as I don't know what you mean what you have tried and what you expect the code to do.(for example give a message) instead of only code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<body>` tag is within your `<head>` tag.